# Android studio project could not find gradle-core jar

Tags: android, gradle

My project was running fine till yesterday. I haven't upgraded my Android Studio. But when I am trying to build my project I am seeing the following error:

```
Could not find gradle-core.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.2)
Searched in he following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/3.1.2/gradle-core-3.1.2.jar
```

Comment: It seems to be a temporary issue of the repository servers. Maybe you can try using Maven Central or the Google mirror as repositories as suggested in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort your repositories like this:

```
jcenter()
mavenCentral()
google()
```

Comment: This works for core-runtime library too.